# cannot import name 'reder_template' from 'flask'

Tags: python, flask

How to fix this error :

> cannot import name 'reder_template' from 'flask' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/**init**.py)

```
from flask import Flask, request, reder_template, redirect
import os
import sqlite3

currentlocation = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

myapp = Flask(__name__)

@myapp.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template("homepage.html")
```

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `render_template`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a typo, you have imported `reder_template` instead of `render_template` from `flask`.